# Value of type '(Class) -> () -> (Class)' has no member 'variable'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, compiler-errors, nsfetchedresultscontroller

```
let fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = { () -> NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult> in
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Message")
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)]
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "friend.name = %@", self.friend!.name!)
    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = delegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    return frc
}()
```

At the line that says: `fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "friend.name = %@", self.friend!.name!)` I get the error: `Value of type '(ChatLogController) -> () -> (ChatLogController)' has no member 'friend'` So apparently it can not find `friend` in my class `ChatLogController` for some reason, or am I wrong? That's what I'm guessing since it wont find `friend` as a member of `self`.

Here is the `friend` variable, it is inside of `ChatLogController` class:

```
var friend: Friend?
{
    didSet
    {
        navigationItem.title = friend?.name

        messages = friend?.messages?.allObjects as? [Message]

        messages = messages?.sorted(by: {$0.date!.compare($1.date! as Date) == .orderedAscending})
    }
}
```

Anyone know why I'm getting this error and how to solve it?

**Edit:** I noticed that if I remove `() -> NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult> in` from the first line of the first code snippet, the error disappears, however instead I get this error: `Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate`

Comment: You need to show both of these snippets of code in the context in which they are declared. For example, in the first snippet, the compiler does not think `self` is a `ChatLogController`, it thinks it is a closure of some description.

Comment: @JeremyP What part of the code do you want to see? And how do I do so that `self` points to the class? Both code snippets that I have shared are within `ChatLogController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared friend as the `optional` property which has not initialised at the time of `initialisation` of fetchedResultsController which is a constant so it's giving the error. To solve this problem you can use `lazy initialisation` which means

> delaying the creation of an object or some other expensive process
>   until it’s needed

make the fetchedResultsController property lazy which will delay creation of object until its required

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = { [unowned self] () -> NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult> in
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Message")
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)]
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "friend.name = %@", self.friend!.name!)
    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = delegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    return frc
}()
```